# JavaScript / Jquery : How to find line-through words

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to find line-through words in a HTML page.

I know how to find the CSS property

```
$(el).css('text-decoration');
```

This returns

```
line-through solid rgb(64, 64, 64)
```

The problem is that the color may differ, and solid might be different too.
So I need something like:

```
 $(el).css('text-decoration').contains('line-through');
```

but that won't work

Comment: `$(el).css('text-decoration').match(/line-through/)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `.css()`returns a string must use javascript string methods.

There are pretty much 
out there pick one. `indexOf, match, regular expressions`

```
$(el).css('text-decoration').indexOf('line-through') // returns -1 if not found
```

Comment: i wonder is there any jquery function called `.contains()` ? i have heard of `:contains()` Please share some info.

Answer (score 0):

[String.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) will help you in this context.

Try,

```
$(el).css('text-decoration').indexOf('line-through')
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(element).css("property")` return `string` in javascript, so use any method of string to find the matching content.

One of the method is `yourstring.indexOf('somestring')`, if found then returns the index of first matched character else returns -1.

```
$(el).css('text-decoration').indexOf('line-through')
```